# I'm confused the use of scanner.next()in JAVA

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

My intention is to print all characters in string. And I want to check if one character is "q" or "Q", just break the loop and end the program. Suppose I use "Hello World You" as input, the output can only be

```
World
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
    at tictactoe.ScannerDemo.main(ScannerDemo.java:22)
```

But if I comment that if statement, the output is correct, which is

```
Hello
World
K
```

So, I don't know why it happens and how to fix it ?
This is my code:

```
public class ScannerDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = "Hello World K";

        
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);

        
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            //if I comment the if statement, the result is normal
            if(scanner.next().equalsIgnoreCase("q")){
                break;
            }

            System.out.println(scanner.next());
        }

        // close the scanner
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The code inside of your `if` statement already consumes one token of the `String` via `next()`. Meaning, on the first loop iteration, `Hello` is consumed, then `World` is consumed in the `System.out.println()`. On the second loop iteration, `K` is consumed, but there is no more tokens for the `System.out.println(scanner.next())` to read, therefore the exception.

Comment: Each call of `next` consumes a full token (delimited by whitespace characters). So if you call `scanner.next().equalsIgnoreCase("q")`, you already consumed a full word. The next call of `scanner.next()` will thus read the **next word**. You have to call it only **once** per iteration and remember the string in a variable instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're calling next() twice without checking if there's a token left...

try

```
while (scanner.hasNext()) {

  String nextValue = scanner.next();
            
  if(nextValue.equalsIgnoreCase("q")){
    break;
  }

  System.out.println(nextValue);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at `scanner.hasNext()` and how often you call `scanner.next()` which is 2x per call to `hasNext()`. Since `next()` returns the next element, the first call will return "Hello" and the second returns "World" as you've already noticed.

Now on the second iteration of the loop there's still a "next" element with the value "You" and that is returned by the call to `next()` in the if-statement. However the next call to `next()` breaks because there is no more input.

To fix that, call `next()` only once and keep a reference to the string:

```
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
   String token = scanner.next();
   if(token .equalsIgnoreCase("q")){
       break;
   }

   System.out.println(token );
}
```

Btw, `I want to check if one character is "q" or "Q"` doesn't match your code as you're only checking entire *strings*. If this is intended behavior then you're ok but otherwise you'd need to use `toCharArray()` or `charAt(index)` to check *individual* characters (this might be weird though, e.g. if input was "may I ask a question: is this printed?" it would stop at "question").

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at your code

```java
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            //if I comment the if statement, the result is normal
            if(scanner.next().equalsIgnoreCase("q")){
                break;
            }

            System.out.println(scanner.next());
        }
```

In the condition of the if statement you are calling next(). This is will not throw any exception cause it is already checked by hasNext() call. But later you are printing the token while not checked by the hasNext() call. Moreover the previous token is lost in the if condition during the next() call.

Try using ..

```java
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String nextToken = scanner.next();
            if (nextToken.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
                break;
            }

            System.out.println(nextToken);
        }
```